# Equating derived classes based on their base's Equals()

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have two classes which both derive from the same parent:

```
public class People{
    public string BetterFoot;

    public override bool Equals(object obj){
        if (obj == null || this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;
        People o = (People)obj;
        return (this.BetterFoot == o.BetterFoot);
    }

public class LeftiesOrRighties: People{
    public string BetterHand;

    public override bool Equals(object obj){
        if (obj == null || this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;
        LeftiesOrRighties o = (LeftiesOrRighties)obj;
        return (this.BetterFoot == o.BetterFoot) &&
        (this.BetterHand == o.BetterHand)
    }
}

public class Ambidextrous: People{
    public string FavoriteHand;
}
```

(There are GetHashCodes in there, too, but I know that they work.)
I'd like to compare collections of them, based on their root Equals():

```
ThoseOneHanded = new List<LeftiesOrRighties>(){new LeftiesOrRighties(){BetterFoot = "L"}};
ThoseTwoHanded = new List<Ambidextrous>(){new Ambidextrous(){BetterFoot = "L"}};
//using NUnit
Assert.That ((People)ThoseOneHanded[0], Is.EqualTo((People)ThoseTwoHanded[0])));
```

Unfortunately, this returns `false`.

Why? Shouldn't the casting make them (for all intents and purposes, if not exactly) the same type, and thus use the base methods? And if not, how do I truly cast the underlying type back to `People`?

Comment: = is the assignment operator.  == is used for equality comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bob Vale pointed out, the `cast` does not change type.

The standard solution used across the .NET Framework is to use custom object implementing [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.aspx) or its generic variant. Then your compare/find method takes 2 objects/collections and uses comparer to perform the custom comparison.

I.e. many `LINQ` methods take custom compare to find/filter objects like 
[Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer
)
```

Sample comparer:

```cs
class Last3BitsComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
{
    public bool Equals(int b1, int b2)
    {
        return (b1 & 3) == (b2 & 3);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(int bx)
    {
        return bx & 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Override Equals(Object other) in both Base and Derived classes, adding the interface doesn't help here.

Answer (score 3):

Cast doesn't change the object itself, so the result of GetType will always be the same and so your `this.GetType() != obj.GetType()` will be true and so the function will return false.

The following logic could potentially gain the behaviour you want (and you don't need to cast to People)

```
public class People 
{ 
    public string BetterFoot; 

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    { 
        var o = obj as People;
        if (o == null) return false;
        return (this.BetterFoot = o.BetterFoot); 
} 

public class LeftiesOrRighties: People 
{ 
    public string BetterHand; 

    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    { 
        var o = obj as LeftiesOrRighties; 
        if ( o == null) return base.Equals(obj);
        return (this.BetterFoot = o.BetterFoot) && (this.BetterHand = o.BetterHand) 
    } 
} 

public class Ambidextrous: People
{ 
    public string FavoriteHand; 
}
```

Comment: Syntax Error- return (this.BetterFoot == o.BetterFoot) //equality operator, not assignment operator